# Solutions pairs for the equation $(4a - b) (4b - a) = 1770n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> How many solution pairs $(a, b)$ of positive integers exist for the equation
>   $(4a - b) (4b - a) = 1770n$,
>   when $n$ is a positive integer?

This one seemed to be pretty tough, it's from Sweden's national contest. How should one approach this?

Comment: Is this helpful?  $4(4a-b)(4b-a)=9(a+b)^2-25(a-b)^2$

Comment: It's not too bad. What have you tried? Where did you get stuck at? E.g. Were you able to conclude that $15 \mid 4a - b, 15 \mid 4b-a $?

Answer (score 1):

The main crux is that $4^2 - 1 \mid 1770$.
You can modify this solution to solving $ (ka-b)(kb-a) = (k^2-1) n$ over the integers, and showing that solutions exist iff $ (k^2 - 1) \mid n$.

---

**Hint:** Show that $ 15 \mid 4a-b, 15 \mid 4b-a$.
Note: This might seem artificial, but it's a very natural result when you start playing with the problem.

> Let $ c = 4a-b, d = 4b-a$.
>  For $ a = \frac{ 4c+d}{15} , b = \frac{ 4c+d}{15} $ to be integers, we require $ c \equiv - 4d \pmod{15}$, and thus $ 0 \equiv 1770 = cd \equiv - 4d^2 \pmod{15}.$
>  Since 15 is square-free, thus $15 \mid d$. Likewise, $15 \mid c$.

---

**Corollary:** Thus, $15^2 \mid (4a-b)(4b-a)$. So if $ 15 \not \mid n$, then there are no solutions.

---

Conversely, if $ n = 15 k$,

**Hint:** Relax the condition to allow for negative $a, b$ for now. Then, the complete set of integer solutions can be described as:

> Let $e,f$ be any pair of integers whose product is $118k$.
>  Then $a = 4e+f, b = 4f+e$.

Clearly, if $e, f$ are both negative, then $a, b$ are also both negative, and we should reject.
If $e, f$ are both positive, then $a, b$ are also both positive.
Hence, the complete set of positive integer solutions is

> Let $e,f$ be any pair of positive integers whose product is $118k$. Then $a = 4e+f, b = 4f+e$.
>  The number of solutions is equal to the number of divisors of $\frac{ 118n } { 15} $.

E.g. When $n = 15$, [we get the solutions](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integer+solutions+%284a-b%29%284b-a%29%3D1770*15) $ (a,b) = (67, 238), (238, 67), (122, 473), (473, 122)$ which arise from $ef = 118$,  $(e,f) = (2, 59), (59, 2), (1, 118), (118, 1)$.